# Свойство “Content” установлено больше одного раза

Tags: c#, xaml

```
Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel x:Name="Nazvania">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Название продукта</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Вес продукта</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
</Window>
```

Ошибка в 13 строчке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что не ясно? Да два раза задан контент. В элемент Window можно вложить только один элемент который и является его контентом. А TextBox уже второй элемент и его надо вносить в StackPanel.

Comment: Пожалуйста, будьте дружелюбны к другим пользователям! Также, было бы хорошо указать что такое "контент" и какие элементы поддерживают больше одного контента, ведь не только StackPanel есть, но и DockPanel, Grid и много других элементов, которые позволяют содержать несколько элементов внутри себя!

Comment: ну и не факт, что `TextBox уже второй элемент и его надо вносить в StackPanel` - возможно, все надо обернуть в другой контейнер, например, другую панель )

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Разве я что-то недружелюбно сказал? :D Вам нужно определение контента? Я даже не знаю... Это все равно что спросить что такое воздух. Слишком просто. А про StackPanel я сказал потому что она использовалась в примере, но да, есть еще много контейнеров. Вообще про это можно почитать вот [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/4.php).

Comment: @DarkByte По поводу негатива - фраза "Что не ясно?" как по мне можно воспринять как "Хах, не черта не знаешь элементарных вещей, ну ты и вася...". Так что я бы лично от таких фраз воздержался бы. Что касается другого - как по мне ответ должен быть развернутым с объяснением каждого аспекта, вот автор вопроса не знает как все устроено, ему бы очень помогло узнать что такое контент, какие элементы принимают один и какие несколько, не все это знают, даже элементарные вещи. По этому стоит на такие вопросы отвечать в более развернутой форме.